# PaintEventArgs.ClipRectangle is always (0,0,0,0) on UserControl

Tags: winforms, user-controls

I am trying to write an EventHandler for a UserControl I wrote,
but for some reason the Control does not seem to have a ClipRectangle:

```
Private Sub paints(sender As Object, p As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(p.Graphics, p.ClipRectangle, SystemColors.AppWorkspace, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
End Sub
```

When I try and add MyBase.OnPaint(p) I get a StackOverflow because for some reason this seems to trigger some endless recursion.

So why is there no Rectangle?
The outline of the UserControl is something like this:
UserControl
- TableLayout
- - TableLayout
- - - Label
- - - Label
- - TextBox

And it should be something like 250x50 pixels.

Comment: You call `MyBase.OnPaint()` when you override the `OnPaint()` method on a derived class. If you subscribe the `Paint()` event of a Control, you don't call `base`/`MyBase`.

Comment: Also, see the [Control.ClientRectangle Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawborder?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.DrawBorder);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PaintEventArgs.ClipRectangle` is a rectangle that **needs** to be painted. If there are no controls on your usercontrol then it is the client area. **But** if there are other controls then it *clips* their area from client rectangle! Probably your child controls occupy the whole client area so there is no need for drawing thus returning `(0, 0, 0, 0)`.